# Why are these routes being matched?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

The following code:

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink(metaTapp.Nav_About, "Mayla", "About")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink(metaTapp.Nav_Support, "Support", "About")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink(metaTapp.Nav_Exchange, "Index", "Exchange")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Post Rfq", "Create", "Rfq")</li>
```

is producing the following links:

```
   <li><a href="/Upload/Image?action=Mayla&amp;controller=About">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Upload/Image?action=Support&amp;controller=About">Support</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Upload/Image?action=Index&amp;controller=Exchange">Exchange</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Upload/Image?action=Create&amp;controller=Rfq">Post Rfq</a></li>
```

My Global Application Start looks like this:

```
  protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            UploadRouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            LocalizationConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory());
        }
    }
```

UploadRouteConfig.RegisterRoutes:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.MapRoute("Upload", "Upload/Image", null).RouteHandler = new UploadMvcRouteHandler();
    }
```

LocalizationConfig.RegisterRoutes

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Account", // Route name
            "Account/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
      "RfqCategory",
      string.Format("{{{0}}}/Rfq/CategoryFilter/{{category}}", Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG),
      new { controller = "Rfq", action = "CategoryFilter", category = Guid.Empty.ToString() }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        Constants.ROUTE_NAME,
        string.Format("{{{0}}}/{{controller}}/{{action}}/{{rfqid}}", Constants.ROUTE_PARAMNAME_LANG),
        new { controller = "About", action = "Home", rfqid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" }
    );
}
```

RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute("TappDefault", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "About", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I cant understand how upload is being matched to everything. If the route doesn't start with Upload/Image it  should fall through to the localizationconfig routes?

Comment: Try defining your `LocalizationRoutes` first before the `UploadROute`

Comment: That doesn't/wont work because then Upload get interpreted as a locale. Also I dont just want it to work but to understand why it doesn't work. My understanding as it stands says Im doing it right so obviously im not but i need to know why so i can "do better" in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the short answer to my problem is that I am rendering ActionLinks when I should be using RouteLinks. ActionLink will perform a match based on route table entries which seems like what I want but because I'm using a static Url:

```
"Upload/Image"
```

every url is matched. Why? Because routes are not filters. Routes work by matching supplied route values to  the parameters of segments of the Url, but since:

```
"Upload/Image"
```

has no parameters i.e. {controller} then technically EVERYTHING is a match. RouteLink on tyhe pother hand allows me to specify which route to use when rendering the link:

```
@Html.RouteLink(
linkText: "route: Home",
routeName: "TappDefault",
routeValues: new {controller="About", action="Home"}
)
```

..

**From Professional ASP.NET.MVC4 (Jon Galloway, Phil Haack, Brad Wilson, K. Scott Allen)**

> Page 232 Chapter 9 Routing:
>
> Let’s suppose you add the following page route at the beginning of
>   your list of routes so that the URL /static/url is handled  by the
>   page /aspx/SomePage.aspx:
>
> routes.MapPageRoute("new", "static/url", "~/aspx/SomePage.aspx");
>
> Note  that  you can’t put this route  at the end of the list of routes
>   within  the RegisterRoutes method  because it would  never match 
>   incoming  requests.  Why wouldn’t it? Well, a request  for /static/url
>   would  be matched  by the default  route  and never make it through
>   the list of routes  to get to the new route.  Therefore,  you need to
>   add this route  to the beginning  of the list of  routes before the
>   default  route.
>
> **NOTE This problem  isn’t speciﬁc to Routing with Web Forms. There are many cases where you might  route to a non-ASP.NET MVC  route
>   handler.**
>
> Moving this route to the beginning of the deﬁned list of routes seems
>   like an innocent  enough  change, right? For incoming requests,  this
>   route will match only requests that exactly match /static/url but will
>   not match any other requests.  This is exactly what you want.  But
>   what about  generated  URLs? If you go back and look at the result of
>   the two calls to Url.RouteLink, you’ll  ﬁnd that both URLs are broken:
>
> ```
> /url?controller=section&action=Index&id=123
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> /static/url?controller=Home&action=Index&id=123
> ```
>
> This goes into a subtle behavior  of Routing,  which is admittedly
>   somewhat of an edge case, but is  something  that people run into from
>   time to time.
>
> Typically, when you generate a URL using Routing,  the route values
>   you supply are used to “ﬁll in” the URL parameters as discussed
>   earlier in this chapter.
>
> When you have a route with the URL {controller}/{action}/{id}, you’re
>   expected to supply values for  controller, action, and id when
>   generating  a URL. In this case, because the new route doesn’t have
>   any URL parameters, it matches every URL generation attempt because
>   technically,  “a  route value is supplied for each URL parameter.” It
>   just so happens  that there aren’t any URL  parameters. That’s why all
>   the existing URLs are broken, because every attempt to generate a URL 
>   now matches this new route.
>
> This might seem like a big problem,  but the ﬁx is very simple. Use
>   names for all your routes and  always use the route name when
>   generating URLs.  Most of the time, letting Routing  sort out which 
>   route you want to use to generate a URL is really leaving it to
>   chance, which is not something   that sits well with the
>   obsessive-compulsive control  freak developer.  When generating  a
>   URL, you  gener- ally know exactly which route you want to link to, so
>   you might as well specify it by name.  If you have a need to use
>   non-named routes and are leaving the URL generation entirely up to 
>   Routing,  we recommend writing unit tests that verify the expected
>   behavior  of the routes and URL  generation within your application.
>
> Specifying the name of the route not only avoids ambiguities,  but it
>   may even eke out a bit of a  per- formance  improvement because the
>   Routing  engine can go directly to the named route and  attempt to use
>   it for URL generation.
>
> In the previous example, where you generated  two links, the following
>   change ﬁxes the issue. We  changed the code to use named parameters to
>   make it clear what the change was. @Html.RouteLink( linkText: "route:
>   Test", routeName: "test", routeValues: new {controller="section",
>   action="Index", id=123})